# Unable to set title while log-in using putty with python

Tags: python, powershell, putty

I am able to login to putty by using below command

```
Popen("powershell kitty-0.73.1.1.exe Name@1.2.3.4 -pw password  -title Firstsession")

Popen("powershell kitty-0.73.1.1.exe Name@1.2.3.4 -pw password  -title Secondsession")
```

Problem is I am unable to set title for powershell, while execution I can see the title as mentioned in above command (Firstsession, Secondsession ) 
but once user is logged in successfully, then title gets cleared title is displayed as

> Name@CentOS-7-App:~

in powershell

I even this tried -classname but still I am unable to get the desired title

```
Popen("powershell kitty-0.73.1.1.exe Name@1.2.3.4 -pw password  -classname Firstsession")
```

I am referring this site for passing parameters

```
https://www.9bis.net/kitty/#!pages/CommandLine.md
```

Answer (score 0):

I have never heard of kitty-0.73.1.1.exe, until now, though I use putty all the time. I am going to assume that, that -title is a kitty-0.73.1.1.exe thing, because, [there is no -Title switch for PowerShell to set the console host title bar.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/About/about_PowerShell_exe?view=powershell-5.1)

To change the PowerShell console host title, the command is:

```
$host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Changed Title'
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.automation.host.pshostuserinterface.rawui

Even that won't display until the console host has fully loaded, meaning process any user profile stuff.

So, from cmd.exe, this will work quickly ...

```
powershell -noexit -noprofile $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Changed Title'
```

However, if there is a bunch of stuff in your profile ...

```
powershell -noexit $host.ui.RawUI.WindowTitle = 'Changed Title'
```

... it will take longer for the title to change

Yet, your question seems to indicate you are trying to change the title bar of the putty console, and I am not sure why one would believe that PowerShell would be able to change another host's environment interactively. You can use PowerShell to start an external program, but it is up to the program to do the rest.